# Adding RAM modules

Tags: memory, compatibility

I have a GigaByte [GA-X58A-UD3R](http://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-X58A-UD3R-rev-20#ov) mother board with the following RAM setup:
[image: ram setup]
Looking at the manual, the only thins it says is how to insert the module, nothing about where to place it or how to arrange multiple modules.
The memory modules are from a [6GB Corsair kit](http://www.corsair.com/en/tr3x6g1333c9) (3 * 2GB, 1333MHz).
If I want to add a new module (let's say a single 6GB 1333MHz), on which slot should I install it?

Comment: Does the manual suggest anything?

Comment: the only thing the manual say is how to insert the module into the slot. there's nothing there about how to arrange the modules

Comment: As it is Socket 1366 it probably has triple channel. If there is nothing on how to use the slots why did you opt to have a space between each module? There should be something in the manual about the usage of the RAM slots. You would probably use the B_1 slot.

Comment: I do suggest you add that to your post :)

Comment: 6GB modules do not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think such a thing as a 6GB module exists, but if you want to put 1 additional module, you can insert it into any slot, will make no difference on your current setup. If you really want to upgrade, sell the 2GB ones and put 3 x 4GB, so the triple channel can function at 100%.

A single module puts less stress on the chipset and consumption will be lower, which is in theory less important than triple channel working. But for most normal applications there will be no visible performance difference with triple channel. See benchmarks [here](http://www.overclock.net/t/681697/the-truth-about-i7-1366-memory-both-dual-channel-vs-tri-channel).

So if you plan to upgrade further at another point in time, get one bigger stick so you can add more later. If not, if you want a single upgrade now, add 3x2 GB or add 3x4GB or add 3x4GB and remove the current 3x2GB.

Comment: Is a single module preferred over 3 separate ones?

Comment: I have updated the answer to include some insight on that.

Comment: Thanks for the update, so if I'll get a new 8GB stick I can just place in any one of the empty slots?

Comment: Yes, but make sure the MB supports 8GB modules (by default or with BIOS update).

Comment: the [specification page](http://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-X58A-UD3R-rev-20#sp) says: `6 x 1.5V DDR3 DIMM sockets supporting up to 24 GB of system memory(Note 1)` does that mean it has the support I need (on a win 10 OS)?

Comment: Modules confirmed to work with your MB : (2x8) 16GB of HyperX Savage 2400mhz CL11; Corsair 8GB part numbers CMX8GX3M1A1333C9 and CMV8GX3M1A1333C9. (Corsair source: http://www2.corsair.com/retailer/product_results.aspx?rid=13251&id=6109689 .)

Comment: @Yoav - It is very likely the only 24GB configuration that will works is 6 4GB modules.